# jQuery .click() works in fiddle but not in real code

Tags: jquery, .net

Programatically firing `click` events seems to be a perinnial problem.  There are lots of SO questions about this and yet none of the solutions I have seen seem to work in my real code.  I have a *working* [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/190319/)  that holds my question.

I am running Visual Studio 2017, C#, .Net 4.6.1, jQuery 3.3.1.  I was getting jQuery, bootstrap, etc from NuGet but started thinking that there might be packaging issues so I have switched to CDNJS.  I am working on a very busy kind of "tree" select widget.

My employer has a space usage database: who is in or can access which rooms; square fottage and other room traits.  I want a widget that allows empolyee-X to request access to one or more rooms.  The rooms are "controlled" by group leader(s), lab manager(s), etc.  This means that I have a hierarchy something like:

```
    |-- Group_1
    |   |-- ConferenceRooms
    |   |   |-- 3252
    |   |   `-- 3374
    |   |-- Labs
    |   |   |-- 1014
    |   |   `-- 4915
    |   `-- Offices
    |       |-- 4919
    |       `-- 7352
    |-- Group_2
    |   |-- ConferenceRooms
    |   |   |-- 1618
    |   |   `-- 7276
    |   `-- Labs
    |       |-- 1333
    |       `-- 5106
    |-- Group_3
    |   |-- ConferenceRooms
    |   |   |-- 1167
    |   |   `-- 9145
    |   `-- Labs
    |       `-- 5789
    |-- Group_4
    |   |-- Labs
    |   |   |-- 1867
    |   |   |-- 2418
    |   |   |-- 7912
    |   |   `-- 8853
    |   `-- Offices
    |       |-- 1328
    |       `-- 4084
    `-- Group_5
        |-- Labs
        |   |-- 6179
        |   |-- 6605
        |   `-- 7015
        `-- Offices
            |-- 1686
            |-- 3418
            |-- 3542
            `-- 5092
```

The widget shows each "directory" as a `ul` until you get to the room numbers.  The room numbers are buttons.  Each button is identical as far as html/css go.  The text values are, of course, different.  There is a visual difference if the user already occupies or otherwise has access to the room and then the button color is different.

The buttons have an `onClick` handler

```
    $("button.roomId").on("click", function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        var count = 0;

        //
        // toggle the selected button
        if ($(this).is("button.disabled")) {
            $(this).removeClass("disabled");

            count = -1;
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("disabled");

            count = 1;
        }

        //
        // put the count in the parent li and trigger onChange in the parent
        $(this).parent()
            .trigger("change", [count]);
    });
```

This passes and maintains a count up through the widget hierarchy.  There are also `onChange` handlers for the `li` and `ul` elements to adjust and pass the counts upward.

When I first build the widget for a particular user, I will know to which spaces that user has access and which room(s) they occuply.  This means that I want to trigger the button clicks after I decorate the associated buttons.

There is a section of code where I build the buttons

```
    //
    // create the per group, per roomType room buttons
    for (let i = 0; i < data[groupName][roomType].length; i++) {
        const roomId = data[groupName][roomType][i];
        var match = false;

        //
        // if this roomId matches any of this user's rooms set
        // "matched"
        Object.keys(sessionCookie.myData).sort().forEach(
            function(key) {
                const re = new RegExp(`^${roomId} \\\(`);

                if (re.test(key)) {
                    match = true;
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            });

        //
        // create the li and the button
        const room = $("<li/>").addClass("list-no-bullet")
            .addClass("d-inline-block")
            .attr("data-key", roomId)
            .appendTo(roomList);

        const button = $("<button/>").addClass("roomId")
            .addClass("itemName")
            .addClass("btn")
            .addClass("btn-sm")
            .addClass("btn-secondary")
            .addClass("mr-1")
            .addClass("p-0")
            .append(roomId)
            .appendTo(room);

        //
        // if this roomId matched this user's list of room then 
        // decorste the button and fire the clicke event
        if (match) {
            $(button).removeClass("btn-secondary")
                .addClass("btn-dark")
                .append(" Occupant");

            $(button)[0].click();
        }
    }
```

In the simplified fiddle, the `$(button)[0].click();` idiom works but not in the code above.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your code can be shortened... `.addClass('itemName btn btn-sm btn-secondary mr-1 p-0');`

Comment: You should **not** do `$(button)[0]`.  What this is doing is taking the DOM Element button, calling jQuery to create a jQuery object containing the button, and then breaking the button out of the jQuery object you just created.  There is no reason to do this.

Comment: Is there any console error? Also, I don't see any click eventhandler associated with `button` like you have in fiddle `$("button.mainButton").on("click", function() {
   $("<p/>").append($(this)
     .attr("data-id") + " clicked")
     .appendTo("div#target");
  });`

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in comments, it is useless to create a jQuery object and not use it.

Additionnally, `button` already is a jQuery object beause of this line:

```
const button = $("<button/>").addClass("roomId")
```

So you simply should use `button`.

Then, to fire a click event on it, use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). That would be:

```
button.trigger("click");
```

It is also mentionned in comments that you have to have a click handler defined too... ;)
I updated [**your Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/7dj8qsL6/) in that way.

Comment: The button's `click` handler is in the first code block above.  Doing `button.trigger("click");` does nothing.  There are no console messages.  It is as though the handler `$("button.roomId").on("click", function(event) {...});` is the wrong handler for this button... but these are the only buttons on the page.

Comment: I updated your fiddle and it is working... Now `$("button.roomId")` defines 3 buttons in your example. So that would trigger a click on each of them. Beyond your minimal example, it can be done very differently. My answer is about the use of jQuery objects and the use of `.trigger()`.